# How to exclude a word or string from an URL - Regex

Tags: php, regex, url

I'm using the following Regex to match all types of URL in PHP (It works very well):

```
 $reg_exUrl = "%\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))%s";
```

But now, I want to exclude Youtube, youtu.be and Vimeo URLs:

I'm doing something like this after researching, but it is not working:

```
$reg_exUrl = "%\b(([\w-]+://?|www[.])(?!youtube|youtu|vimeo)[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))%s";
```

I want to do this, because I have another regex that match Youtube urls which returns an iframe and this regex is causing confusion between the two Regex.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just filter out unwanted domains in a second step? or even more better: third step. The second step should be URL normalization. Then it's pretty easy and much more robust.

Comment: FYI The original answer was general, but I added a regex specifically for your situation.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @hakre, but I don't know too much about regular expressions and happens that I have a comment system, then, what I want to do  is to detect all the urls (to make them clickable with "href"), hashtags (search) and urls of youtube (iframe), and I have to do all this at the same time when I get the data from the database to show it finally to the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

socodLib, to exclude something from a string, place yourself at the beginning of the string by anchoring with a `^` (or use another anchor) and use a negative lookahead to assert that the string doesn't contain a word, like so:

```
^(?!.*?(?:youtube|some other bad word|some\.string\.with\.dots))
```

Before we make the regex look too complex by concatenating it with yours, let;s see what we would do if you wanted to match some word characters `\w+` but not youtube or google, you would write:

```
^(?!.*?(?:youtube|google))\w+
```

As you can see, after the assertion (where we say what we **don't want**), we say what we **do want** by using the \w+

In your case, let's add a negative lookahead to your initial regex (which I have not tuned):

```
$reg_exUrl = "%(?i)\b(?!.*?(?:youtu\.?be|vimeo))(([\w-]+://?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/)))%s";
```

I took the liberty of making the regex case insensitive with `(?i)`. You could also have added `i` to your `s` modifier at the end. The `youtu\.?be` expression allows for an optional dot.

I am certain you can apply this recipe to your expression and other regexes in the future.

**Reference**

1. [Regex lookarounds](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)
2. [StackOverflow regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075)