# How to map fallback in ASP .NET Core Web API so that Blazor WASM app only intercepts requests that are not to the API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor WebAssembly solution with a client project, server project and shared project, based on the default solution template from Microsoft. I'm editing and debugging in Visual Studio 2019 preview with Google Chrome.

Out-of-the-box, the solution has a single start-up project, which is the server application. That server application has a project reference to the client application. You can set it to use HTTPS by checking "Enable SSL" in the server project properties and I have done that.

When you click on debug it works perfectly.

Now I want to change it so that the Blazor WASM app only responds to requests from https://localhost:44331 and not requests to https://localhost:44331/api. These requests should be dealt with by API Controller endpoints of the server application instead. So, if somebody visits https://localhost:44331/api/something, and no such API endpoint exists, they should receive a 404 error code from the API and not be routed to the usual Blazor page saying "Sorry, there's nothing at this address."

I want to use this extra "/api" portion of the URL to keep the requests to the API separate from requests for pages. I think this will be closer to how a normal setup would be in production. I hope it's clear what I'm trying to do.

Here is a sample Controller declaration with route attribute:

```
namespace BlazorApp2.Server.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        // Etc.

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            //etc.
        }
///etc.
    }
}
```

Here is what I have tried in my Startup.cs and it does not work. Can anybody suggest something that will please?

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // Etc.
    app.UseStatusCodePages();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        // The line commented out below is the out-of-the-box behaviour for a Blazor WASM app with ASP NET Core API. This is the line I want to replace.
        // endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

        // The line below is my (failed) attempt to get the behaviour I want.
        endpoints.MapFallback(HandleFallback);
    });
}

private async Task HandleFallback(HttpContext context)
{
    var apiPathSegment = new PathString("/api"); // Find out from the request URL if this is a request to the API or just a web page on the Blazor WASM app.

    bool isApiRequest = context.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(apiPathSegment);

    if (!isApiRequest)
    {
        context.Response.Redirect("index.html"); // This is a request for a web page so just do the normal out-of-the-box behaviour.
    }
    else
    {
        context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound; // This request had nothing to do with the Blazor app. This is just an API call that went wrong.
    }
}
```

Does anybody know how to get this working how I'd like, please?

Comment: Can you post a sample of your API controller route ?

Comment: Sure I will. I'll put it in my question in a moment

Answer (score 26, accepted):

To recap the problem, when somebody makes a request to:

```
https://yourapp.com/api/someendpoint
```

and `/api/someendpoint` can't be found, they're taken to a Blazor page. This default behaviour is weird. For requests starting with `/api`, they were expecting an HTTP Status Code and probably a JSON object too, but instead, they got HTML. Maybe they don't even use your app. Maybe they're not even human (more likely they're a piece of software).

This is how you send them an HTTP Status Code instead.
On your controllers:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleController : ControllerBase
{
    // ...
}
```

In Startup.cs:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ...
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.Map("api/{**slug}", HandleApiFallback);
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{**slug}", "index.html");
    });
}

private Task HandleApiFallback(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: I come late to this (I'm investigating another problem, anyway), but I think that a more flexible solution to this scenario is using something like:                  endpoints.MapFallbackToController("<some pattern>", "controller name");

Comment: Great question and answer!  One nitpick, I'd suggest changing `return Task.FromResult(0);` to `return Task.CompletedTask;` as it's more clear and idiomatic.

Comment: That's a fair point. Thank you. I'll update it.

Comment: The issue I'm seeming to face is that with this method, if you try to POST `api/path` rather than GET `api/path`, you're getting a 404 instead of a `MethodNotAllowed`. Any way to correct this? 404 is very unhelpful in debugging if you have the method wrong.

Comment: i solved my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844850/526704

Comment: 501 Not Implemented would be better

Answer (score 12):

You can fix this by explicitly mapping Blazor fallback only for paths that don't start with `/api` and, then only mapping api paths for those that do start with `/api`, like I mention in [this answer to my owner question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844850/526704). This gives the benefit that instead of just returning a `404` if you try to `POST` to a `GET` api method, you will get the proper api response of `405`, or whatever other error the api would normally return given the request.

```cs
//explicitly only use blazor when the path doesn't start with api
app.MapWhen(ctx => !ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), blazor =>
{
    blazor.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    blazor.UseStaticFiles();

    blazor.UseRouting();
    blazor.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });
});

//explicitly map api endpoints only when path starts with api
app.MapWhen(ctx => ctx.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api"), api =>
{
    //if you are not using a blazor app, you can move these files out of this closure
    api.UseStaticFiles();
    api.UseRouting();
    api.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
});
```

Comment: This worked for me. .net 6 blazor wasm hosted with aadb2c. I don't get why localhost works without this change but on azure needs this solution.

Comment: This saved me for another unrelated Blazor issue ,thanks a ton!

Comment: There should be something similar in the framework (I'm on .NET 7) ... thanks

Answer (score 10):

Pretty sure this should work:

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("{*path:regex(^(?!api).*$)}", "index.html"); // don't match paths beginning with api
```

I think it means something like only match URLs where the path does not start with api.

Comment: With .NET 6 blazor I get the following error with this method: `ArgumentException: 'index.html' is not a valid page name. A page name is path relative to the Razor Pages root directory that starts with a leading forward slash ('/')`

Comment: This is probably the best solution here only you need to use MapFallbackToFile as it is intended for static files rather than MapFallbackToPage which is intended to map to a Razor page.

Answer (score 1):

Using code from @Darragh I get the following error:

endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("{*path:regex(^(?!api).*$)}", "index.html");

> System.ArgumentException: ''index.html' is not a valid page name. A
> page name is path relative to the Razor Pages root directory that
> starts with a leading forward slash ('/') and does not contain the
> file extension e.g "/Users/Edit". (Parameter 'pageName')'

[image]

The code will run if I use `MapFallbackToFile` instead of `MapFallbackToPage` like the original code.

However when I tested the regex it matched everything including an API URL:

https://regex101.com/r/nq7FCi/1

My Regex would look like this instead: `^(?!.*?(?:\/api\/)).*$` based on this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23207219/3850405

https://regex101.com/r/qmftyc/1

When testing this out It did not work anyway and urls containing `/api/` was redirected to `index.html`.

My final code is based on @benjamin answer but with the original `MapFallbackToFile` used last.

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
    endpoints.Map("api/{**slug}", HandleApiFallback);
    endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
});

private Task HandleApiFallback(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status404NotFound;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
}
```

Comment: the regex should only be tested against the 'path' segment...not the absolute URL

Comment: Can you explain what doe {**slug} stands for here ?

Comment: @NSS You can find some useful info form https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing#route-template-reference

Comment: The issue I'm seeming to face is that with this method, if you try to `POST api/path` rather than `GET api/path`, you're getting a 404 instead of a 1MethodNotAllowed`. Any way to correct this? 404 is very unhelpful in debugging if you have the http method wrong, or any other error that might happen gets overwritten by a 404

Comment: I solved my issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69844850/526704

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use regex101 to test the negative look ahead (the `?!`) since regex101 doesn't use the more featureful .NET Regex Engine.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this with Blazor WebAssembly .NET 5. After publishing to IIS, the previously suggested solutions do not work.

The answer to this question is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67452439/blazor-webassembly-app-api-call-from-browser-sorry-theres-nothing-at-this). **Tested and working.**

Shortly:

Edit *wwwroot\service-worker.published.js* file and add the path to exclude, in this case `/api/`.

```js
const shouldServeIndexHtml = event.request.mode === 'navigate' &&
                             !event.request.url.includes('/api/')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you start from a Blazor WASM hosted solution, you'll a get a sample, just launch

```sh
dotnet new blazorwasm --hosted
```

It create a solution with 3 projects :

|-- Client
|-- Server
|-- Shared

In The Server `Startup` class, the middleware pipeline is setup like this :

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
        endpoints.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
    });
}
```

The controller define its route with [`Route`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#custom-route-constraints) attribute. If you want to host the controller at */api/{controller}* use the `Route` attribute value `api/[controller]`:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained this properly. Starting with this default template you posted above, but now you want your API endpoints to be served from URLs starting with "api" like https://localhost:44331/api/weatherforecasts and you want your Blazor pages to be served from URLs that do not start with "api" like https://localhost:44331/fetchdata.

Comment: So, if somebody enters an API endpoint, you don't want the Blazor app to be involved at all. So visiting  "https://localhost/4331/api/somethingnotthere" does not result in a Blazor page that says "Sorry, there's nothing at this address". It just results in a simple Http Status Code response of 404. I hope that's clear what the goal is now.

Comment: Well, I don't get why you want this behavior but BTW you can wrote a middleware checking for unknown routes

Comment: Can you explain to me why you would want the default behaviour, please? The default behaviour is that somebody has made an API request, expecting an Http status code and probably a JSON object, but instead they ended up at an HTML page on a Blazor application. Maybe they never used your Blazor app before and were only interested in using your API. Maybe they aren't even a human;API requests can come from other software too. So, in my opinion, the default behaviour is weird, and the behaviour I'm trying to create is normal.... Am I wrong?

Comment: Yeap, in that case write a middleware to check known URLs returning a 404 if the URL is not in a pre defined table.

Answer (score 0):

With all other solutions applied, I still encounter the problem in ASP.NET Core 7 (not sure if the version matters) and it **only happens on Production server**. Turned out there's this difference between dev and production environment:

```cs
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error"); // <-- This line
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}
```

Removing `app.UseExceptionHandler` and I can see exceptions again.