# Blazor / .NET 8 / Web API in Blazor server project is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor, .net-8.0

I have started a new Blazor project with the new .NET 8 auto setup.

I am trying to place a Web API controller in my server project and use my ASP.NET identity authentication functionality to verify someone is logged in etc.

Here is my API controller setup:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestDataController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment environment;

    public TestDataController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
    {
        this.environment = environment;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        string path = Path.Combine(environment.WebRootPath);

        string returnData = $"filename: {"1"} | path: {path}";

        return Ok(returnData);
    }
}
```

Then in my client side project I have this setup:

`Program.cs` in client project:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("WebAPI",
client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.Configuration["BaseAddress"]));

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
    .CreateClient("WebAPI"));
```

Razor.cs

```
@page "/api-call"
@using App.Client.Services
@using System.Net.Http.Headers
@using Syncfusion.Blazor.Buttons
@using System.Text.Json

@inject IHttpClientFactory HttpClientFactory
@inject CookieService CookieService
@rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly

<h3>ApiCall</h3>

<SfButton OnClick="onToggleClick" Content="Click Me"></SfButton>

@if (APIValue != null)
{
    <h3>@APIValue</h3>
}
else
{
    <span>
        Loading products...
    </span>
}

@code {

    private string APIValue { get; set; }

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
    }

    private async Task onToggleClick()
    {
        var httpClient = HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("WebAPI");

        //var cookie = await CookieService.GetCookieValue("YourCookieName");

        // httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        //             new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", cookie);

        try
        {
            APIValue = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<string>("TestData");
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException ex) // Non success
        {
            Console.WriteLine("An error occurred.");
            APIValue = $"error {ex.Message}";
        }
        catch (NotSupportedException) // When content type is not valid
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The content type is not supported.");
        }
        catch (JsonException) // Invalid JSON
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid JSON.");
        }
    }
}
```

I keep seeing the error:

> No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44309/api/testdata

What am I missing to make it work?

I do not have the authorize attribute on the controller yet because I was just going to test it first without logging in.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blazor and Webapi are using different routing system. To make controllers work in Blazor, you need to add

```
builder.Services.AddControllers();
...
app.MapControllers();
```

Also make sure your controller is setup as such

```
namespace MyApp.Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api")]
    public class TestDataController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment environment;
        public TestDataController(IWebHostEnvironment environment)
        {
            this.environment = environment;
        }

        [HttpGet("GetWeatherForecast")]
        public string Get()
        {
            string path = Path.Combine(
                                environment.WebRootPath);

            string returnData = $"path: {path}";

            var myData = new MyData
            {
                Id = returnData,
                DateTime = DateTime.Now,
            };

            string jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(myData);

            return jsonString;
        }
    }

    public class MyData
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Following url: [Host web api in blazor server application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70583469/host-web-api-in-blazor-server-application/75565364#75565364)

Comment: Qiang Fu -> I have those in my Program.cs for my Blazor Server app: https://localhost:44309/api/TestData/main -> this still gets a 404.

Comment: @tvb2754 do you also get 404 when visit the url directly?

Comment: I think I got it! I had to follow this along with your post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565364. I will mark yours as answer and then try to add another answer with it all unless you just want to update yours? Basically, I had to change my controller setup to the stackoverflow link I provided.  So I guess it is really an MVC Controller acting as a web api controller?

Comment: @tvb thx:) I didn't mention that it should be inherit from "ControllerBase"

Answer (score 1):

I think this

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class TestDataController : ApiController
```

Should be

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestDataController : ControllerBase
```